# VideoView "Can't play this video"

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a video in a videoView, but I can't get it to play.
Here's my java code:

```
package com.ggblbl.videoView;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class RandomVideoBlueActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_video_blue);

        VideoView videoBlue = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewBlue);
        String videoPathBlue = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.blue_video;
        Uri videoUriBlue = Uri.parse(videoPathBlue);
        videoBlue.setVideoURI(videoUriBlue);
        videoBlue.start();
    }
}
```

My video name is *video_blue.mp4*.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iefnweekgbb9owz/blue_video.mp4?dl=0

Here's my activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ggblbl.videoView.RandomVideoBlueActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoViewBlue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tested it on my LG L70 (D320n).
On my Motorola Moto G1 it does work, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some testing and it seems the resolution of the video is too high for my poor, old phone...
I guess I'll have to find a way of scaling it down for every phone.